# Return a file attachment on web request using python script without using django

Tags: python-2.7

I have used **httplib.HTTPResponse** it working fine if i return a string/dict but not able to return it as a attached file.
using **django.http.HttpResponse** its possible to do but i dont want to use django for this.
I am trying to do it simply writing a python script, hosted on mod-python apache webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the effect you want, at an HTTP level need to have a [`Content-Disposition` header](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) as part of the HTTP response:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=whatever.ext
```

The `whatever.ext` will be used by user agents to prompt the user as a sensible filename to save as, or just to save it directly depending on configuration.

However you're going to run into trouble doing this with `httplib.HTTPResponse`, which is not designed either for developers to create them or for creating responses that will go back over the wire. You're probably better off using either [the built-in `cgi` module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html), or something lightweight such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).